# Jquery Importing Data from URL with Login

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Google Chrome extension to put autocomplete in certain fields on the internal wiki. It does a JQuery script inject. Anyway, the autocorrect fields are on a webpage, behind a login. After one logs in, the browser prompts you to download an HTML file, and the file is in json format. That's the data I need to load into the autocomplete. So far my script looks like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Thanks for visiting!");

    var data = $.ajax({
        url: "URL",
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
    });

    function setAutocomplete(){
        $("input").autocomplete({
            source: [data]
        });
    };

    $("#COST_JOB_NUM").live("click", function(){
        setAutocomplete();
    });

});
```

I know there's no log in credentials there so it can't be working, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. I know the autocomplete plugin itself works, so it's an issue of getting the data. Any help?

Comment: Is this data on a different domain?

Comment: Yes, it's on a different domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content scripts are not allowed to make cross-domain ajax requests (just like regular scripts on a page).

You would need to move your ajax request to a background page that doesn't have such limitation (as long as you declared corresponding host permissions in the manifest).

You can communicate between content script and background page through [messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html).